# Pygame collide with object opens new window

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm currently working on a little pygame, to a school project. I ran into a problem that I don't know what to do about. The game is basicly a original snake game, with a little twist. Whenever the snake collide with one of the foods, there is going to popup a new window. I don't know how to make that popup window. I researched a bit on it and there is something called Tkinter, that can make a popup window. Hopefully you can help me.

The code I'm working on atm.

```
    import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from Tkinter import *

def collide(x1, x2, y1, y2, w1, w2, h1, h2):
    if x1+w1>x2 and x1<x2+w2 and y1+h1>y2 and y1<y2+h2:return True
    else:return False
def die(screen, score):

    f=pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 40);t=f.render('Du fik: '+str(score)+' point', True, (0, 0, 0));screen.blit(t, (10, 50));pygame.display.update();pygame.time.wait(2000);sys.exit(0)
xs = [300, 300, 300, 300, 300];ys = [290, 270, 250, 230, 210];key = 0;score = 0;applepos = (random.randint(0, 590), random.randint(0, 590));pygame.init();s=pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600));pygame.display.set_caption('Snake');appleimage = pygame.Surface((20, 20));appleimage.fill((0, 0, 0));img = pygame.Surface((20, 20));img.fill((255, 0, 0));f = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20);clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:

    clock.tick(20)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit(0)

        elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == K_UP and key != 0:key = 2
            elif e.key == K_DOWN and key != 2:key = 0
            elif e.key == K_LEFT and key != 1:key = 3
            elif e.key == K_RIGHT and key != 3:key = 1
    i = len(xs)-2
    while i >= 2:

        if collide(xs[0], xs[i], ys[0], ys[i], 20, 20, 20, 20):die(s, score)
        i-= 1

       #This is here where the windows gonna popup after it collide with the object.
    if collide(xs[0], applepos[0], ys[0], applepos[1], 20, 20, 20, 20):score+=1;xs.append(700);ys.append(700);applepos=(random.randint(0,590),random.randint(0,590))                                  

    if xs[0] < 0 or xs[0] > 580 or ys[0] < 0 or ys[0] > 580: die(s, score)
    i = len(xs)-1
    while i >= 1:
        xs[i] = xs[i-1];ys[i] = ys[i-1];i -= 1
    if key==0:ys[0] += 20
    elif key==1:xs[0] += 20
    elif key==2:ys[0] -= 20
    elif key==3:xs[0] -= 20 
    s.fill((255, 255, 255)) 
    for i in range(0, len(xs)):
        s.blit(img, (xs[i], ys[i]))

    s.blit(appleimage, applepos);t=f.render(str(score), True, (0, 0, 0));s.blit(t, (10, 10));pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: `#This is here where the windows gonna popup after it collide with the object.
    if collide(xs[0], applepos[0], ys[0], applepos[1], 20, 20, 20, 20)`, the `if` syntax is invalid.

Comment: I have edited the code please try again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a message box when snake colides, you have to add

```
import tkMessageBox
```

and

```
Tk().wm_withdraw()
tkMessageBox.showerror(title, message)
```

In

`if collide(xs[0], applepos[0], ys[0], applepos[1], 20, 20, 20, 20):score+=1;xs.append(700);ys.append(700);applepos=(random.randint(0,590),random.randint(0,590))`

Like this:

```
if collide(xs[0], applepos[0], ys[0], applepos[1], 20, 20, 20, 20):
    score+=1
    xs.append(700)
    ys.append(700)
    applepos=(random.randint(0,590),random.randint(0,590))                                  
    Tk().wm_withdraw()
    tkMessageBox.showerror(title, message)
```

Comment: When I try it says I need to define "NameError: name 'tkMessageBox' is not defined". What do I define it as?

Answer (score 0):

Since you should create only one root window, you have to use a Toplevel to open a new one.

```
def newWindow():
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.title('Another window')
    toplevel.focus_set()
```

Comment: Not really what i'm looking for. After the collide with a object, I need a new window to popup. Nothing else. Can you help me with this? :)

Comment: I changed my previous answer.